# Speed up estimation of overlapping additive models (mgcv)

Tags: r, feature-selection, spline, gam, mgcv

I have some set of variables and I'm fitting many (hundreds of thousands) additive models, each of which includes a subset of all the variables. The dependent variable is the same in every case, and some of the models overlap or are nested. Not all of the independent variables have to enter the model nonparametrically. For clarity, I might have a set of variables `{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}` and estimate:
a) `y=c+f(x1)+f(x2)`,
b) `y=c+x1+f(x2)`,
c) `y=c+f(x1)+f(x2)+x3`, etc.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to speed up the gam estimation in this case? Is there anything that is being calculated over and over again that I could calculate once and supply to the function?

What I have already tried:

- Memoization since the models repeat exactly from time to time.
- Reluctantly switched from thin plate regression splines to cubic regression splines (quite a significant improvement).
- The mgcv guide says:

  > The user can retain most of the advantages of the t.p.r.s. approach by supplying a reduced set of covariate values from which to obtain the basis - typically the number of covariate values used will be substantially smaller than the number of data, and substantially larger than the basis dimension, k.

  This caused quite a noticeable improvement with smaller models, e.g. 5 smooths, but not with larger models, e.g. 10 smooths. In fact, in the latter case, it often caused the estimation to take (potentially much) longer.

What I'd like to try but don't know if it's possible:

- One obvious thing that repeats itself in both, say, `y=c+f(x1)+f(x2)` and `y=c+x1+f(x2)`, is the calculation of the basis for `f(x2)`. If I were to use the same knots every time, how (if it's possible at all) could I precalculate the basis for every variable and then supply that to mgcv? Would you expect this to bring a significant time improvement?

Is there anything else you'd recommend?

Comment: I have to ask *why* you are doing this?; any reasonable inference after doing this would be invalid. You have the [tag: feature-selection] tag and this sort of approach gives me the fear. I'm assuming you cant fit the model with all covariates as smooths and penalize even the linear parts of the bases with shrinkage smooths or `select = TRUE`. And assume you've tried `bam()` and running multiple models in parallel?

Comment: I'm working on a method for selecting variables for a predictive model (so I'm not worried about inference) - an alternative to `select = TRUE` in a way. And yes, in some cases I can't fit the model with all covariates. Yes, I've tried `bam()` (takes much longer than `gam()`) and I do estimate models in parallel - these must've slipped my mind earlier.